# How can i make sure content scripts are injected to all frame only if parent url matches?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions, manifest.json

I have an iframe on a page. My requirement is to inject content script to all frame within a page, only when the Main Frame(URL on Omni bar) matches given URL.

developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts 
I don't see a way. Can you suggest me a way to achieve my target?

Comment: I think `"all_frames": true` in manifest.json + `if (window !== top)` check in the content script to skip processing inside iframes on irrelevant top URLs. Or you can inject manually via chrome.tabs.onUpdated (it supports filters in Firefox) + chrome.tabs.executeScript. BTW your doc link is for apps, here's the correct one: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts

Comment: window !==top -> will result in loading Content script only on main window. I want to inject on all frame only when url of main window matches a pattern.

Comment: Well, simply add a check for location.href too, seems trivial.